# JMeter: how to asign a single distinct value from CSV Data Set Config to each thread in thread group?

Tags: performance, testing, load-testing

I have to make a load test for a relatively large number of users so I cant really use User Parameters pre-processor to parametrize each thread with custom user data. I've read that I should use CSV Data Set Config instead. However I run into a problem with how JMeter interprets the input of this Config.

Example:

I have a thread group of 3 threads and Loop Count:10 with one HTTP request sampler with server `www.example.com` and path: `\${user}`.
The csv file (bullet is a single line in file) for CSV Data Set Config to extract the user parameter:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5

Expected output is that for thread 1-x the path of the request should be: \x. So the output file should consist of 10 samples per thread namely:

- for thread 1-1 : 10 requests to `www.example.com\1`
- for thread 1-2 : 10 requests to `www.example.com\2`
- for thread 1-3 : 10 requests to `www.example.com\3`

but instead i get requests to each \1 - \5 and then to EOF. Does anyone know how to achieve the expected effect with CSV Data Set Config in jmeter 2.9?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out:

Set thread group loop to 1.
Enter a Loop Controller with desired number of loops **after** the CSV Data Set Config. Add the HTTP request sampler as a child of Loop Controller and you got it:)

Image of config:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

#### Case 1

When you know number of occurrences to be substituted in the existing request:

- Take a loop counter define it with loop count as the number of occurrences you need to substitute.
- Insert a CSV data set config as child into it and a Counter (this will generate that many occurrences variable.)
- Use a beanshell to fetch the values from CSV data set config and assign it to variable generated by counter.
- Outside the loop you can keep you sampler request which has the the values to be substituted.

#### Case 2

When you have  number of occurrences to be substituted in the dynamic request

- Take a loop counter define it with loop count as the number of occurrences you need to substitute fetched from previous sampler request
- Insert a CSV data set config as child into it and a Counter (this will generate that many occurrences variable.)
- Use a beanshell to fetch the values from CSV data set config and assign it to variable generated by counter.
- Inside the loop you can keep you sampler request which has the the values to be substituted.

Comment: Sequential Each Occurrence in same request: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3nagpYyXQ8&t
Random and Unique Each Occurrence in same request: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x97uFKXceyE&t

Answer (score 0):

Put CSV Data Set Config under Once Only Controller.

[image]